# Sass-loader not replacing variables?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, sass-loader

Not too long ago I made a project that used a combination of SASS variables and CSS custom properties.  I defined my Sass variables and then used those to create my CSS custom properties.  Everything worked great.  Now I'm trying to do the exact same thing, using the same code and loaders (Webpack) and it's not working and I can't figure out why.

I have a `style.scss` file that looks like this:

```
$var1: #ff3344;
h1 { color: $var1; }
:root { --color1: $var1; }
```

When I build my project with Webpack using `sass-loader`, `css-loader`, and `style-loader` I get the following output:

```
h1 { color: #ff3344; }
:root { --color1: $var1; }
```

For some reason, the `$var1` gets replaced for the `h1` but not for the `--color1`.

Seeing as I did this before with no issue, I expected `sass-loader` may be the cause.  But I downgraded `sass-loader` to 6.0.7 which was the same version I used in the project that this worked in but I'm still having this issue.  Why isn't `sass-loader` replacing `$var1` when it gets assigned to `--color1` ?

Comment: are you sure this worked? :root { --color1: $var1; } .Existing sass compilers doesn't convert this

Comment: On the other hand this works :root { --color1: #{$var1}; }

Comment: I'm sure.  Here's some sample code from my working project:

`:root {
    @each $name, $color in $page-colors {
      --color-#{$name}: $color;
    }
  }`

Comment: I guess using `#{}` will work.  But I dont understand why I didn't have to do that in my previous project.  I had about 100 CSS properties assigned to Sass variables just like above and it worked fine.

Comment: Try comparing the node-sass version. It could very well be a bug in the new version

Comment: That's it!  This new version of `node-sass` is what's causing it.  Before it let me do it this way, now it doesn't.  Thank you karthick!

Comment: No problem. happy coding and debugging

Answer (score 8):

> Custom variable values only support SassScript inside `#{}`.

For example if you want to have array of colors:

```
$blue:    #007bff !default;
$indigo:  #6610f2 !default;
$purple:  #6f42c1 !default;
$pink:    #e83e8c !default;
$red:     #dc3545 !default;
$orange:  #fd7e14 !default;
$yellow:  #ffc107 !default;
$green:   #28a745 !default;
$teal:    #20c997 !default;
$cyan:    #17a2b8 !default;

$colors: () !default;
$colors: map-merge((
  "blue":       $blue,
  "indigo":     $indigo,
  "purple":     $purple,
  "pink":       $pink,
  "red":        $red,
  "orange":     $orange,
  "yellow":     $yellow,
  "green":      $green,
  "teal":       $teal,
  "cyan":       $cyan,
  "white":      $white,
), $colors);

@each $color, $value in $colors {
    --#{$color}: #{$value};
}
```

Comment: Docs on this: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/css-vars

Comment: Btw: pasting „Custom variable values only support SassScript inside #{}“ inside a SCSS code comment will break compilation at the `#{}` inside a comment.